# Monitor a Log File in Real Time with VB? (VS 2012 Express & Win 7)

Tags: vb.net, file, logging, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a small form/app in VB that will monitor a log file. Another application constantly writes to the log, and I'd like to somehow read anything new that was written and display it in a textbox in real-time.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is not yours, then you would need to read that file's modified time stamp or size using a timer in your new application.

If that other application is yours, write a send message using windows sendmessage API from other application to your application.

Comment: It's not my application, so sending a message is impossible. I can check with a timer, but I still don't have a way to *display* the additions to the file in real time.

Comment: Conting the lines or characters in the file will help you. Keep track of the old count then compare to new count.